# Problem loading out-of-tree module

Tags: linux, kernel, module

I'm trying to load an out-of-tree module, exactly the same way I was doing it on past kernels with success. But with 5.15.27, it longer works:

`$ insmod /lib/modules/5.15.27custom/extra/mymodule.ko`

`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.15.27custom/extra/mymodule.ko: Invalid parameters`

dmesg says:

`[61204.361302] mymodule: disagrees about version of symbol __stack_chk_fail`

`[61204.361326] mymodule: Unknown symbol __stack_chk_fail (err -22)`

`CONFIG_STACKPROTECTOR` and `CONFIG_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG` are set in .config, if that matters.

Can anyone help me on how to make that module loadable (or rebuild so it can be loaded)?

Comment: Silly question, but you have recompiled it against the running kernel source?

Comment: No, the running version is 4.15.0-187-generic (Ubuntu 18.04, which I'need for compiling for a very scruffy embedded OS). But that was never an issue.

Comment: Then you have a problem. You are saying the running kernel version is 4.15.0-187-generic, and yet, the above error shows 5.15.27custom. If you have compiled it again that v5 kernel, then there is no chance of loading it in the running v4.

Comment: No, I'm trying it to load into a 5.15.27custom system, but building on a 4.15.0-... system! ;)